# OpenCV close window with mouse issue

Tags: opencv, window, mouseevent

OpenCV version 2.2, C++ interface.

When showing a loaded image in a window with following code snippet

```
cvStartWindowThread();

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image );   

while( 1 ) {
    if( cvWaitKey(100) == 27 ) break;
}
```

I face a problem when closing image by pressing the `close button` with the mouse, instead of using escape key.

In this case my program will be blocked in the `while` and the only way to exit it is to stop execution, which obviously is not desired.

Is there any function that controls if the `close button` has been pressed?
In that way I could add it in the while loop as this:

E.g.

```
while( 1 ) {
    if( cvWaitKey(100) == 27 ) break;
    if( cvCloseButtonPressed == 1) break; <--- purely invented method I'm looking for...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `cvGetWindowHandle()` function to get handle of your named window. Window handle is an OS specific feature.
An example for win32 looks like this:

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("Display window");
while(IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) {
    if( cvWaitKey(100) == 27 ) break;
}
```

IsWindowVisible() is a winapi function, so you may want to add `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: @MichalKottman actually it's working also on linux with g++ compiler, with just a little different sintax. This is the function I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Note: It seems not working for Windows + MinGW compiler, due to a bug in opencv's implementation on MinGW??    I don't know when it will be fixed, or perhaps it is already fixed (since I don't regularly update to the most recent version).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of showing the image in a loop, try showing it only once:

```
imshow("Display window", image);
waitKey(0);
```

The `waitKey(0)` means ["wait forever"](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!cvGetWindowHandle(windowName.c_str())) {
    destroyAllWindows();
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Add a bit more text so readers can understand what you're trying to achieve.