# Python: how to capture image from webcam on click using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I want to capture and save a number of images from my webcam using OpenCV. This is my code currently:

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
for i in range(10):
    return_value, image = camera.read()
    cv2.imwrite('opencv'+str(i)+'.png', image)
del(camera)
```

The problem with this is that I do not know when the images are being taken, so a lot of them end up blurry. My question is: **Is there a way to have the image taken on the click of a keyboard key?**

Also is there a better way to take multiple images, instead of range?

Comment: I don't think there's any need for `del(camera)`

Answer (score 110):

Here is a simple program that displays the camera feed in a `cv2.namedWindow` and will take a snapshot when you hit `SPACE`.  It will also quit if you hit `ESC`.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I think this should answer your question for the most part.  If there is any line of it that you don't understand let me know and I'll add comments.

If you need to grab multiple images per press of the `SPACE` key, you will need an inner loop or perhaps just make a function that grabs a certain number of images.

Note that the key events are from the `cv2.namedWindow` so it has to have focus.

Comment: It would be complete if you included the line where people can change the location of storing those images. anyway great works

Comment: Is it possible to break the loop if X is pressed on the streaming window?

Comment: @TheHog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307606/closing-video-window-using-close-x-button-in-opencv-python

Answer (score 10):

Breaking down your code example (Explanations are under the line of code.)

```
import cv2
```

imports openCV for usage

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

creates an object called camera, of type openCV video capture, using the first camera in the list of cameras connected to the computer.

```
for i in range(10):
```

tells the program to loop the following indented code 10 times

```
    return_value, image = camera.read()
```

read values from the camera object, using it's read method.
it resonds with 2 values
save the 2 data values into two temporary variables called "return_value" and "image"

```
    cv2.imwrite('opencv'+str(i)+'.png', image)
```

use the openCV method imwrite (that writes an image to a disk) and write an image using the data in the temporary data variable

fewer indents means that the loop has now ended...

```
del(camera)
```

deletes the camrea object, we no longer needs it.

you can what you request in many ways, one could be to replace the for loop with a while loop, (running forever, instead of 10 times), and then wait for a keypress  (like answered by [danidee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3734244/danidee) while I was typing)

or create a much more evil service that hides in the background and captures an image everytime someone presses the keyboard...

Answer (score 5):

i'm not too experienced with open cv but if you want the code in the for loop to be called when a key is pressed, you can use a while loop and an raw_input and a condition to prevent the loop from executing forever

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0
while i < 10:
    raw_input('Press Enter to capture')
    return_value, image = camera.read()
    cv2.imwrite('opencv'+str(i)+'.png', image)
    i += 1
del(camera)
```

Comment: Change the "raw_input()" function to "input()" function if you're using Python3.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple program to capture an image from using a default camera.
Also, **It can Detect a human face**.

```
import cv2
import sys
import logging as log
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep

cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
log.basicConfig(filename='webcam.log',level=log.INFO)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
anterior = 0

while True:
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print('Unable to load camera.')
        sleep(5)
        pass

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30)
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    if anterior != len(faces):
        anterior = len(faces)
        log.info("faces: "+str(len(faces))+" at "+str(dt.datetime.now()))


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'): 

        check, frame = video_capture.read()
        cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
        cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img.jpg', img=frame)
        video_capture.release()
        img_new = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img_new = cv2.imshow("Captured Image", img_new)
        cv2.waitKey(1650)
        print("Image Saved")
        print("Program End")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        break
    elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        print("Turning off camera.")
        video_capture.release()
        print("Camera off.")
        print("Program ended.")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**output**

[image]

Also, You can check out my GitHub [code](https://github.com/Antu7/webcam-face-detection-with-image-capture/blob/master/webcam.py)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple programe to capture a image from using laptop default camera.I hope that this will be very easy method for all.

```
import cv2

# 1.creating a video object
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
# 2. Variable
a = 0
# 3. While loop
while True:
    a = a + 1
    # 4.Create a frame object
    check, frame = video.read()
    # Converting to grayscale
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # 5.show the frame!
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)
    # 6.for playing 
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
# 7. image saving
showPic = cv2.imwrite("filename.jpg",frame)
print(showPic)
# 8. shutdown the camera
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

You can see my github code [here](https://github.com/humayun-ahmad/machine-learning/tree/master/cv2%20module)

Comment: Thanks. @Robot, you can check now.