# How do I capture images using webcam in Python?

Tags: python, webcam, image-capture

There are certain libraries such as fswebcam, cv2 etc. But pip cant find a matching distribution for Python3 on Win7 64bit. Are there any other libraries or how can i use these two to capture images from Python

Comment: `pip install python-opencv` does this work?

Comment: No matching distribution

Comment: `pip install opencv-python`  .. later use `import cv2` in the script

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588464/python-how-to-capture-image-from-webcam-on-click-using-opencv

Comment: Try [VideoCapture](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#videocapture).

Answer (score 0):

I installed openCV on my 64-bit windows 10 machine using openCV and numpy wheels, which I installed using pip.

You can find the numpy wheels here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

And the cv2 wheels here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Make sure you find the wheels specific to your setup, ie. 64-bit with python 3.6, use:
numpy‑1.14.5+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

Save those in a folder, then navigate to that folder in a command window and install the files using pip.

The full guide is here if needed:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is that you have both Python2 and Python3 installed, and therefore pip only works for Python 2. You can install OpenCV as follows:

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

You have to make sure Python 3 has been added to the system path and the command `Python3` is available. If the executable file of Python 3 is named **Python**, just rename it to **Python3**.