# How to make USB camera work with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, windows-7-x64

I copied code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588758/210342 and used with default (built-in) camera, it worked. Then I attached USB camera, tested it with VLC and changed the code to open camera `1`:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

I check whether the camera is open `cam.isOpened()` -- it is -- but the camera is not enabled (its hardware indicator, LED, is off) and indeed all I see on the screen is black frame.

Is there some extra special code to add in order to enable USB camera?

Comment: Are you sure the usb camera is camera 1, i've done this before and had to use cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: @Stanley, big THANK YOU! :-) I could spend no matter how much time and I wouldn't guess the numbers are shuffled after attaching USB camera. Could you please post your comment as regular answer?

Comment: Thank you, it's almost an "honour" for me as a self taught programmer to be able to help experienced programmers! goes to show that everyone can learn something from anyone. Again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure the usb camera is camera 1, i've done this before and had to use cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Answer (score 15):

You can also refer this link here

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027250/how-to-use-usb-webcam-in-jetson-tx2-with-python-and-opencv-/

Here he changes the line below to

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video1") # check this
```

Before plugging in the camera, go to your terminal home

1. Type `cd /dev`
2. Type `ls video` and then press tab, if you find only result as `video0`, that means only webcam is present.
3. Now repeat 1 to 2 with USB webcam plugged in. You should find `video1` or `video2` when you repeat the steps.

Comment: The post above specifically calls out that this is for Windows (via the tag). The path `/dev/video1` is a Linux device path. This doesn't exist in the same way on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem, turns out sometimes the webcam can take both slots 0 and 1.
So `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)` worked for me. This was found using the `cd /dev`-method above.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why but on my laptop (Acer Aspire 3) the usb webcam works with python opencv only if I plug it in the right side usb of my laptop and NOT if I plug it in the left side usb. So try plugging the webcam on **all the usb ports you have**. (I also had to use `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)` as @Slayahh suggested.

Answer (score 1):

in accordance to the accepted answer and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60603969/4451944

i realized `cv2.VideoCapture(4)` the parameter 4 is directly proportional to the file suffix of `/dev/video4`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the LED indicator turned on, but there was read returned none. Somehow the solution was to call call cv2.VideoCapture again.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
_ = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```