# How to access the usb camera opencv

Tags: opencv

I can able to access the inbuilt laptop camera with the following code

```
import cv2
#import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()        
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I connected a USB camera. I gave 1 instead of 0 to access it. but it is showing an error. By changing it to between -1 and -99, I can access the inbuilt cam only. How can I access the USB cam? I checked the working condition of USB cam with cheese. It is working fine.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029233/how-to-make-usb-camera-work-with-opencv, you may find that the usb camera number is actually 0 .

Comment: 0 - getting inbuilt laptop camera but for usb camera what to change