# How to take picture in cv2,python after a specific period of time

Tags: python, opencv, time

With cv2 and python, to take picture every specific amount of time
eg: 5 mins

Comment: And what have you tried?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [timeloop](https://github.com/sankalpjonn/timeloop) library. If you can already take a picture, it should enable you to run the task periodically.

Installation is straightforward using pip

```
pip install timeloop
```

See the sample code in the documentation

```py
import time
from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta

tl = Timeloop()

@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=2))
def sample_job_every_2s():
    print "2s job current time : {}".format(time.ctime())
```

In case you need help taking a picture using cv2 there are some great answers on this platform already showing how to do that, [this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588464/python-how-to-capture-image-from-webcam-on-click-using-opencv)

Comment: Are you sure you want to introduce a new dependency for something that can be done with a few lines of code?

Comment: There's a few options in time and threading, but considering the question needed to be asked in the first place, I thought it's better to have something easy to use that doesn't need the user to worry about concurrency and blocking.