# Close Opencv window using Close button

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv

I have seen lot of examples in opencv exampes to Exit a window by pressing "ESC" key. I am working in a windows platform where I need to use the close button in the window to close the opencv "Capture" window? How can I do it? Any suggestions and examples will be helpful.

Comment: The short answer is you need to process the `WM_CLOSE` message appropriately.  Is that where you're having trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenCV doesn't support this feature.** [Sorry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9887310/176769)!

Answer (score 3):

I think this type of a code will help. I usually do this for closing window in python.

```
while():


    if (cv2.getWindowProperty('name_of_window', 0) < 0):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```